# Python: how to print exponential equations in matplotlib?

Tags: python, text, matplotlib, textbox, equation

I need to print the following equation on matplotlib using `plt.text()`:

`y=1.5*exp(-0.5x)-0.05`

I've used this line, but my plot does not show the equation anywhere:

```
a=1.5
b=-0.5
c=-0.05
plt.text(2, 2, '$y=%3.7sexp+%3.7sx+%3.7s$'%(a, b, c), fontsize=20)
```

What do you reckon is the problem? Or is there another fancy way of writing this equation, maybe using the exponential the way we were taught at school?

Comment: Have you checked the x-axis and y-axis scale in your plot? You've set up the `text` coordinate at `(2,2)` in your code. If you move the coordinate within the scale of your plot then you should see the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of testing I've figured out that this solves the problem:

```
a=1.5
b=-0.5
c=-0.05
plt.text(60, 0.6, '$y=%3.7s*e^{%3.7sx}%3.7s$'%(a, b, c), fontsize=15)
```

As pointed out by @Andreas Hsieh, the first two arguments refer to the x- and y-scale we have in the plot, so that it is easy to figure out how to call that precise spot where you want the text to be.

The lines

```
rsquared=0.917568
plt.text(60, 0.5, '$R^{2}=%3.7s$'%(round(rsquared,3)), fontsize=15)
```

can be used very efficiently to also overwrite the R squared value, as does Microsoft Excel in the regression, or any other value (e.g., the p-value).